# Javascript Basic Login Function

Tags: javascript

can any1 explain it to me why this isnt working?
Here's the script

```html
<script type= "text/javascript">
function login() {
var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
if(user == "lab18" && pass == "lab18") {
    alert("Logged In");
    locate="new11.html"
    return false;
} else {
    alert("wrong user/pass");
    return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

And here's the form:

```html
<form name="Form" onsubmit="login()">
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" style = font-family:'Comic Sans Ms'>
```

Comment: Just a heads up.. If you are checking the password on the client-side, then anyone can see what the password is in plain-text.

Comment: what is not working ? alert ? redirect ?

Comment: i know, thanks. Im just kinda learning functions this way not making anything special.
Neither one is working.

Comment: If you just want to see the different "alert" boxes pop up, you can put the login() function call in the onclick event of an html button.  Also, both sections of your if statement are returning 'false' which you probably don't want, but here, they're of no consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note that when you submit the form, it'll redirect the user to the the page specified by the `action` attribute. That being said, your form lacks an `action` or `method`. You can read more about how to construct a proper form [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Not handling your JavaScript inline with your HTML is a good habit to get into, so I suggest you add an event listener to your form. Consider the following revisions:

I removed the `onsubmit` attribute from your form and gave it a unique ID:

```
<form id="myForm" name="Form">
```

Now let's add an event handler for when your form submits (since you don't seem to want the form to *actually submit*, we can prevent that default behavior from happening):

```
document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    // Prevent the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
    // login() will be called when the form is submitted
    login();
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aoxLdk0p/)**